# stop location updating on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-location

I am using following code to stop location updating

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = nil;
```

But still after calling thing function the location services are not stopped and still tries to find the location , can any one help me what I have done wrong.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `locationManager` actually an instance of CLLocationManager or is it possible that it's `nil` ? Please verify via debugger or `NSLog(@"%@", locationManager);`. Because if it's `nil`, then you won't get an error but simply nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust - I found the solutions, I got idea from your comment....

Comment: Where I was calling the Location manager, the values were NULL and due to that I was not able to stop the location services update, I resolved that and called this function in didUpdateToLocation: method and now working exact.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following link could help you I guess.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2299-cllocationmanager-stopupdatinglocation-not-working.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when it wouldn't stop updating location. I didn't try to nil the delegate though, because the problem was that in my "locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:" method was called other method before actually stopping updating location, i called my own method (download objects from server). It was okay until i had to download too many. I guess the deal is that it tries to download them too long for "didupdatelocation" to be called over and over again.

**I thought of two solutions for that** (for me at least):

1. Do stuff AFTER stopping manager. - That didn't work for some reason, i still had multiple calls.
2. Do stuff asynchronously. - That seemed to work well for me.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Normally the code you used [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; should work for stop updating location. But if that won't work then you can have one alternative soltion as follow:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

`{
firstTime = TRUE;
}`

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

```
if(firstTime = TRUE)
{
    firstTime = FALSE;
    current_Latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    current_Longitude= newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

}

Here you can use one BOOL variable to check whether you updated the location or not.

Comment: 1) Please format your post. 2) If you use an instance variable they default to `NO` which you should take advantage of, so you should test for `NO` (or `FALSE`) instead of `YES` (or `TRUE`). Variable name should reflect that. Otherwise you'd have to initialize the variable in your `init`. 3) In your `if`, you've (accidentally?) done an assignment instead of a comparison, the term will always be true.